# Unable to Send email using microsoft Graph API using delegated permission with Username and Password provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to send email using UserNamepassword provider with delegated permission but getting error as below
AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Trace ID: 66ecbe3d-56d1-4850-8310-dd33cb8d3900 Correlation ID: b2f61146-44d3-4997-ab99-5370bbac6b04

When I tried with Application permission with send.mail, I am able to send email as any user.
but as per the company restrictions i need to send email using delegated permission.
How to achieve this as error is with respect to Multi factor authentication as MFA has been enabled on our account.

IPublicClientApplication publicclientapplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
.Create(clientId)
.WithTenantId(tenantId)
.Build();

UsernamePasswordProvider authprovider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicclientapplication, scopes);

await graphServiceClient.Me
.SendMail(email, false)
.Request().WithUsernamePassword("Username", passwordstring(stringpassword))
.PostAsync();

Please help here with options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has multi-factor authentication (MFA) enabled, then you can’t use username/password to obtain tokens, because **ROPC flow** does not support MFA,  according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc):

> If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to
> the application, they will be blocked instead.

The easiest way is to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), which supports users with **MFA** enabled to log in to the application. When using this flow, you need to log in to the user to obtain the authorization code, and then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: But if I want to use Auth code flow, I need to have Send.mail application permission (send email as any user). Is that correct?

Comment: @Devika  Yes, if you send emails as any user  (`/users`) you need Mail.Send **application permissions**, if you are sending mail on behalf of a logged-in user (`/me`) you need Mail.Send **delegated  permissions**.